# Selenium IDE (Firefox) - Select box

Tags: selenium

I want to automate my testing so I'm currently studying selenium. How can I automate the testing of a select box (which is not actually a select box) but a javascript populated input box...

[image]

I've tried click, clickandwait, etc but nothing works.. I even tried calling the javascript method but it doesn't also work.. please help.. I need to select the EURO value so that it can trigger another javascript function..

[image]

Please give me an idea if what I want to achieve in Selenium is possible or not.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.  I used C#, not sure what you have used, but this might give you a thought.

```
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> divs =  ie.FindElement(By.ClassName("dropdownDiv")).FindElements(By.TagName("div"));
            foreach (IWebElement div in divs)
            {
                if (div.Text.Contains("EURO"))
                {
                    div.Click();
                }
            }
```